# Write output that will be read by System.in, java

Tags: java, unit-testing

Is there a way to write to an outputstream that will be read by the System.in input stream?  For example:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.in));
```

Except that doesn't work because System.in is an input stream and OutputStreamWriter takes an outputstream.

I want to output something that will be read by:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

What I am trying to do is write a unit test for a console application.  I want to programatically test my input.  Any way to do this would answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is that you make methods with method(String/int var) and have a separate parser.  Then you can test all methods without having to have an input. This is standard in unit-testing.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look to `setIn()` method from `System` object.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn%28java.io.InputStream%29

It will let you reassign the System input stream.

Comment: +1  I'm taking the suggestions about unit testing but I really appreciate this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can write and read to stdin/stdout, but I would refactor your code to separate out  *how* you get your input from *what* you do with it.

That way you can call the "do it" code directly from your unit test.

It also allows other input sources to be plugged in to your code, such as file contents, web page contents, etc with ease.